# reading power levels from a charging battery via USB in C#

Tags: c#, usb, power-management, batterylevel

I have had a little experience with USB communication via C#.My question today is this.

Is there a way to find the % or otherwise level of a battery connected via USB? I am designing an application to check the charge in a battery that charges via a USB connection.

The initial idea came from seeing the [Logitech K750 Solar](http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/products/keyboards/articles/8603) Powered Wireless USB Keyboard that comes with a Solar app, enabling the total charge of the keyboard to be monitored whilst plugged in.

[Solar app's Screenshot](http://pinglio.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/pinglio_k750solarapp.png)

The battery I wish to monitor has no specific tech other than to limit the 5v USB supply down to 4.2v and cut off charging once the battery reaches full.